# stat gives No such file or directory

Tags: c, freebsd, stat

I have the following code in C. I run it at FreeBSD. I compile it as `cc -o bbb bb.c`. Then run and get the output

```
$ ./bbb
-1    
stat: No such file or directory
```

This is the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
    struct stat *st;
    int stat_code =0;
    stat_code = stat("/", st);
    printf("%d\n", stat_code);
    perror("stat");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's being overly nice to you, might have been worse, considering you pass uninitialized pointer to stat.

Comment: well, i pass "/" not sure how it can be uninitialized?

Comment: @Alexandr: Not *that* pointer. The other one.

Comment: What do you think that `st` **pointer** is *pointing to* ??

Comment: Thank you. it seems i misunderstood what is pointer. Now is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the the function prototype for stat() from **man 2 stat**

> int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);

Your code will get segmentation fault, because address of structure variable need to pass in stat() function.

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

   int main() {
        struct stat st;
        int stat_code =0;
        stat_code = stat("test.txt", &st);
        printf("%d\n", stat_code);
        perror("stat");
        return 0;
    }
```

above will help you. For reference

> man 2 stat

Answer (score 1):

`int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);`

The `stat()` function shall obtain information about the named file and write it to the area pointed to by the buf argument. The path argument points to a pathname naming a file.

In your code `stat("/", st);` is path for directory only.